# Image part as background without scaling

Tags: html, css

I need help with my notification box.

I want to have a background image which is a sprite with multiple icons. I only want the light bulb.

Here's a snippet:

```css
.focus-info {
    background: #fff5ec url("https://www2.pic-upload.de/thumb/32630279/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 14px -1085px;
    border: 1px solid #fd823e;
    color: #d06124;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 12px 0 0;
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 48px;
}

.focus-info.notification {
    background-color: #fefdf5;
    border-color: #e3b600;
    color: #b4920d;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<em class="focus-info notification">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

<br><br>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</em>
```

In this snippet you can see the background with the other icons if the text gets larger. How can I set the `background-size` to `20x30px` but without sizing the whole box?

If I just add `background-size: 20px 30px`, the picture is scaled and I can't see the light bulb anymore.

I don't want to add an element which have only the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add an element for the background, you can use `:before`.

Add a `:before` style for `.focus-info` class and set the background in it.

```css
.focus-info:before {
 background: #fff5ec url(https://www2.pic-upload.de/thumb/32630279/sprite.png) no-repeat scroll 0px -1094px;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

.focus-info {
    border: 1px solid #fd823e;
    color: #d06124;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 12px 0 0;
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 48px;
    position:relative;
}

.focus-info.notification {
    background-color: #fefdf5;
    border-color: #e3b600;
    color: #b4920d;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<em class="focus-info notification">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

<br><br>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</em>
```